# Need help writing and reading from JSON for a discord bot

Tags: node.js

I am using the code from this example: [Save JSON file to grab other data from it later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420471/save-json-file-to-grab-other-data-from-it-later)

I copied and pasted this code just to test it and make sure that it worked and when I run it but when I do i get this error:

```
undefined:1
{
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/vishnu/Documents/DiscordBot/index.js:5:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

I'm new to node.js so i'm still trying to understand this a bit. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the content of the file you are reading ? Make sure it starts with a `{` character and there are no invisible characters

Comment: it is just {} nothing else

Comment: Check for any invisible character or encoding error.

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that amount of `{` symbol mismatches amount of `}`